VS Code firefox-debug unable to hit breakpoints for angular app (docker)
I am running:

ubuntu 24.04
VS Code installed, with firefox-debug extension
Docker compose my web app

I can launch a browser hosting my web app from VS Code, but I am not able to hit any breakpoints. Googling the issue gives me tons of similar hits, but none of the solutions work (if still applicable at all, because a lot use configs in launch.json that are no longer existing).
Of course, I can set breakpoints in Firefox, but that's a rather annoying way to debug issues, so I really prefer to have it working again in VS Code (I had it working years ago, but things have changed in the extension it seems).
My launch.json:
{
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch firefox (docker)",
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200/",
      "profileDir": "/home/bas/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/t3usrk2w.Development",
      "keepProfileChanges": true,
      "tmpDir": "~/temp",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "url": "webpack:///src",
          "path": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
        },
        {
          "url": "http://localhost:4200",
          "path": "${workspaceRoot}/src/*"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

For what's it worth, a screenshot of how firefox sees the mapping:

Side question, I don't need anything besides the above mentioned on my host PC right? I don't need to install anything for angular, since all is running in docker. It should be just VS Code + firefox debug etx, find the correct launch json and that should be all right?
